# regularity of a cardinal,exponentiation

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

How it follows for an infinite cardinal $\lambda$ from
$\lambda = \lambda^{<\lambda}$ that $\lambda$ is in fact a regular cardinal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\lambda$ is singular, what can you say about $\lambda^{\operatorname{cf}(\lambda)}$?

Comment: $>\lambda$, thank you for a hint...

Comment: And also $\leq\lambda^{<\lambda}$, don't forget.

Comment: Sorry, I've deleted my comment:But $\lambda=\lambda^{<\lambda}$ is an assumption.It may be the case for a regular $\lambda$ that $\lambda < \lambda^{<\lambda}$,right? But you have stated the opposite inequality which is always true: $\lambda\leq \lambda^{<\lambda}$

Comment: Yes, that is correct. E.g., if CH fails then $\lambda=\aleph_1$ is an example.